# how to get a subprocess to not get stuck if application crashes?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess

I am launching a series of subprocess one after the other, something like

```
for variables in my_list:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(**variables)
    proc.wait()
```

however if one of them crashes Windows pops up a window saying that the program has stopped working; since the process hasn't been killed yet, the program waits until I click the "close program" button

[image: damn_you_windows]

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell Python to open this process without UI or make it so that if it crashes it doesn't pop up error reports. The documentation doesn't seem to address any of this.

I'm using python 2.7, so I can't make use of the `timeout` flag that is present in python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error mode is inherited by child processes. Set it via ctypes. For example:

```
import ctypes
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS = 1
SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX = 2

prev_error_mode = kernel32.SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | 
                    SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)
```